# How to display data equal relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

So,i'm just a new at a laravel.
I have problem with equal relationship.
I just wannna selected my data by quiz_id and display id in preview but it just show it all the data.
i don't have clue what i should do.
I hope you all can give some clue about it

My view :

```html
<form action="/groups/preview/index/question" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
          <div class="tab-content py-4">
            <div class="con-quiz-details">
                <div class="cs-quiz-details">
                  @foreach ($master_quizzes as $master)
                  <div class="banner-quiz">{{ $master->title }}</div>
                  @endforeach
                </div>
                @foreach ($master_questions as $quest)
                <div class="cs-quiz-details">
                    
                  <div class="cs-quiz-header">
                    
                    <div class="mb-3">

                  <div class=""></div>
                  
                      <label for="title" class="form-label soal-quiz">{{ $quest->questions }}</label>    
                      
                    </div>
                    <h6 class="respon mt-5"></h6>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $quest->answer_a }}" value="{{ old('answer_a') }}" readonly>
                        <div class="input-group-text ">
                            <input class="form-check-input mt-0 question-radio" id="correct_answer" type="radio" name="correct_answer[0]" value="A" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                        </div>
                        @error('answer_a')
                          <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{ $message }}
                          </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $quest->answer_b }}" value="{{ old('answer_b') }}" readonly>
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <input class="form-check-input mt-0 question-radio" id="correct_answer" type="radio" name="correct_answer[0]" value="B" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                        </div>
                        @error('answer_b')
                          <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{ $message }}
                          </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="answer_c" name="answer_c[]" aria-label="Text input with radio button" placeholder="{{ $quest->answer_c }}" value="{{ old('answer_c') }}" autocomplete="off" readonly>
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <input class="form-check-input mt-0 question-radio" id="correct_answer" type="radio" name="correct_answer[0]" value="C" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                        </div>
                        @error('answer_c')
                          <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{ $message }}
                          </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="answer_d" name="answer_d[]" aria-label="Text input with radio button" placeholder="{{ $quest->answer_d }}" value="{{ old('answer_d') }}" autocomplete="off" readonly>
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <input class="form-check-input mt-0 question-radio" id="correct_answer" type="radio" name="correct_answer[0]" value="D" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                        </div>
                        @error('answer_d')
                          <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{ $message }}
                          </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="answer_e" name="answer_e[]" aria-label="Text input with radio button" placeholder="{{ $quest->answer_e }}" value="{{ old('answer_e') }}" autocomplete="off" readonly>
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <input class="form-check-input mt-0 question-radio" id="correct_answer" type="radio" name="correct_answer[0]" value="E" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                        </div>
                        @error('answer_e')
                          <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{ $message }}
                          </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                   
                  </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
      </form>
```

My Controller :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Kelas;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Master_question;
use App\Models\Master_quiz;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;



class PreviewController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $kelas = Kelas::all();
        $master_quizzes = Master_quiz::all();
        $master_questions = Master_question::all();
        return view('groups.preview.index', [
            'title' => 'preview',
            'users' => User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->get(),
            'master_question' => Master_question::where('quiz_id', auth()->user()->id)->get(),
            'kelas' => Kelas::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->paginate(2),
            'groups.quiz.question', 'master_quizzes' => $master_quizzes,
            'master_questions' => $master_questions,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        return view('preview.index', [
            'user' => $user
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        return view('preview.index', [
            'user' => $user
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

My routes:

```html
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ClassesController;
use App\Http\Controllers\QuestionsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\MemberController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\EmailController;
use App\Http\Controllers\TimeController;
use App\Models\Kelas;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DiscoverController;
use App\Http\Controllers\MessagesController;
use App\Http\Controllers\FolderController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Report\Html\Dashboard;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profile;

use App\Http\Controllers\FullCalenderController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PreviewController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home', ['title' => 'Login']);
});

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login')->middleware('guest');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate']);
Route::post('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout']);

Route::get('/setup-password/{token}', [PasswordController::class, 'edit'])->name('setup-password-get');
Route::post('/setup-password', [PasswordController::class, 'update'])->name('setup-password');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'ceklevel:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/groups/members/{kelas:slug}/addmember', [EmailController::class, 'show']);
    // Route::get('/groups/quiz/index', [TimeController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/groups/quiz/index', [TimeController::class, 'create']);
    Route::get('/groups/quiz/question', [QuestionsController::class, 'create']);
    Route::get('/email', [EmailController::class, 'kirim']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'ceklevel:admin,user']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', function () {
        return view(('home.index'), ['title' => 'home']);
    });
    Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/classes', [ClassesController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/classes/index/checkSlug', [ClassesController::class, 'checkSlug']);
    Route::get('/groups/{kelas:slug}/posts', [PostsController::class, 'show']);
    Route::get('/groups/{kelas:slug}/folder', [FolderController::class, 'show']);
    Route::get('/groups/members/{kelas:slug}/member', [MemberController::class, 'show']);
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile');
    Route::get('/discover', [DiscoverController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/messages', [MessagesController::class, 'index']);
});

Route::post('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'upload']);
Route::post('/groups/quiz/question', [QuestionsController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/groups/quiz/index', [TimeController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/groups/{kelas:slug}/preview/index', [PreviewController::class, 'index']);
Route::resource('/profile', ProfileController::class)->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('/classes/index', ClassesController::class)->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('/groups/members/addmember', EmailController::class)->middleware('auth');

Route::get('fullcalender', [FullCalenderController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('fullcalenderAjax', [FullCalenderController::class, 'ajax']);



// Route::post('kirim', [EmailController::class, 'kirim']);
```

My Database:

[image: master questions]

[image: master quizzes]

Comment: What is the `selected quiz_id`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you mean by 'wanna selected my data in preview'? It looks like you are retrieving everything with the `all()` queries (not what I would expect from a 'preview'). Also, please trim the code you pasted from the Controller and Routes, there is a lot of code unrelated to your question.